# Test case suggestion for incompressible flow with ALE method on deforming grids

Tags: testing, navier-stokes, incompressible

I'm working on a finite-volume discretization method with implicit time-integration for the incompressible Navier-Stokes equations in Arbitrary Lagrangian-Eularian (ALE) form. So far I've tested the implementation using manufactured solutions similar to the ones by [Etienne e.a., JCP 228 (2009)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jcp.2008.11.032). However, I'm also looking for a test case which

- is physically meaningful (e.g. flow around moving objects)
- has prescribed motion (not true fluid-structure interaction)
- needs deforming grids (not just rigid-grid motion)
- is not too complicated (a complete fighter plane is too much),
- is preferably 3D (because some methods will work in 2D but not in 3D)
- is more or less standard (results by others and/or experiments available for comparison)

This would be ideal but other suggestions for testing flow simulations on deforming grids are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

One example that meets some (certainly not all) of your criteria is flow in a flexible tube in Badia, Quaini, and Quarteroni SIAM J. Sci. Comput. 30 (2008) pp. 1778ff.  There are also some straight tube examples in the PhD thesis of Fabio Nobile.  The advantages of these straight flexible tubes is mostly in relation to your last point, in that there are some results in the literature and some experiments, often under the label of "Womersley flow".

Answer (score 2):

Check [Turek-Hron FSI benchmark](http://adhesion.ucd.ie/ccm/CCM_II_files/Turek%20and%20Hron%20-%20Proposal%20for%20numerical%20benchmarking%20of%20fluid-structure%20interaction%20between%20an%20elastic%20object%20and%20laminar%20incompressible%20flow.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this example](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0045793010002045). Its simple but 2D. All the best.